# Cyrllic characters in SVG font

Tags: javascript, svg, unicode, encoding, fonts

You will have to bear with me with this, as I know very little about encodings so may be asking something very simple/obvious. I am working with some SVG fonts in browser-side Javascript and I need to pull out some information on Cyrillic characters grammatically.

I am doing this currently with latin characters, which is easy as they are stored like so:

```
<glyph unicode="I" horiz-adv-x="573" d="M139 0v1513h281v-1513h-281z" />
```

I can just parse the xml and do a match on "I" to get the information I need. However, I cannot see any Cyrillic characters in the XML. I can see many characters in the following format:

```
<glyph unicode="&#x25fc;" horiz-adv-x="1136" d="M0 0v1137h1137v-1137h-1137z" />
```

I have no idea what the code in the unicode attribute represents (other than a character in unicode format obviously).

Can anyone recommend how I could convert a Cyrillic character to this format? For example the character `п`.

**UPDATE**

I just did a bit of digging and found an article on wikipedia with a list of unicode characters. Looking at [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) you can see that there is a column called 'Decimal' that matches the format in the example above. However if you go to the [section of the list of Cyrillic chars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Cyrillic) there is no mention of decimal codes. Is this just because nobody has entered this information on the wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`п` would be `&#1087;`

To get the code point of a unicode character in JavaScript you can use [`String.prototype.codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) method, in your case just type this into developer console:

```
"п".codePointAt(0)
// 1087
```

To convert the other way around:

```
String.fromCodePoint(1087)
// "п"
```

The format in your example, `&#x...` is a number in hexadecimal notation, so `"п"` could be also represented as `&#x43f`. Conversion:

```
(1087).toString(16)
// 43f
```

So the character `&#xa8;` in your comment would be `¨`:

```
String.fromCodePoint( parseInt('a8', 16 ) )
```

Comment: Ok great thanks, a lot of the char codes seem to be in this format `&#xa8;` you any idea what base that number is in?

Comment: @jcvandan it's a hexadecimal notation, details edited into the answer :)